# sync data form a non android fitness tracker with low energy Bluetooth

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, fitbit

I am exploring the following scenario. Android app that syncs data form a fitness tracker with low energy Bluetooth that is, however NOT running on Android Wear (tracker name: fitbit flex) with a Smartphone running Android 4.3+.

Hence I guess I won’t be able to sync data via Android’s Wearable Data Layer API.  In addition, health related tracking data should only be stored  in house. Hence subscribing to any of the Webservies including the fitbit api is problematic.

I guess then my only option is to get the data directly from the tracking device.  Would I be able to access structured tracking data by simply hooking into the Bluetooth channel? Would it be more efficient/reliable to use Android Wear enabled tracking devices instead. Is there any one that could give me a strategic advice or point me in the right direction?

Comment: You can connect to a Fitbit tracker via BLE (at least I have done so using iOS apps, so I assume you can on Android too), but decoding the FitBit data (as opposed to the standard BLE data like manufacturer and battery level etc) will be tricky as their data format isn't documented - so you will need to reverse engineer it.  It is probably easier to get a tracker that is supported by Android Wear

Comment: I found this - so you may be able to use it to get the data from a FitBit - https://bitbucket.org/benallard/galileo

Comment: @Paulw11 - "Synchronize your fitbit tracker with the fitbit server using the provided dongle"  I'm not sure if that project will be any help for an Android project wanting to use the in-built BLE (and not the dongle that comes with the fitbit).

Comment: The included dongle is just a custom BLE device. This project is the only one I found that interprets the data from the Fitbit. There is still a lot of work required to incorporate the decoding into an Android app, which is why I said it might help - it certainly isn't the solution. The bit that uploads it to then Fitbit service isn't relevant.